# Why is my file data being lost in transfer?

Tags: javascript, upload, xmlhttprequest

Ok, so I found this method for uploading large files from a diferent question:

```
function sliceit(file)
{
    fr = new FileReader;
    chunkSize = 1000000;            

    chunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
    chunk = 0;
    var isstart = true;

    function loadNext() {
        start, end,
        start = chunk * chunkSize;
        if (start &gt; file.size)
            start = end+1;
        end = start + (chunkSize -1) &gt;= file.size ? file.size : start + (chunkSize -1);
        fr.onloadend = function(e)
        {
            while(!fr.result || fr.result == &quot;&quot; || fr.result == undefined)
            {
            }
            fdata = fr.result;
            xmlhttp, form, data;
            data = {};
            data.filename = document.getElementById(&quot;filename0&quot;).value;
            data.username = document.getElementById(&quot;username&quot;).value;
            data.password = document.getElementById(&quot;password&quot;).value;
            data.public = document.getElementById(&quot;public&quot;).value;
            if(isstart)
            {
                var form = new FormData();
                form.append(&quot;filename&quot;, data.filename);
                form.append(&quot;username&quot;, data.username);
                form.append(&quot;password&quot;, data.password);
                form.append(&quot;public&quot;, data.public);
                form.append(&quot;filebytes&quot;, fdata);
                xmlhttp = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                xmlhttp.open(&quot;POST&quot;, &quot;../MakeEmptyFile.php&quot;, false);
                isstart = false;
            }
            else
            {
                form = new FormData();
                form.append(&quot;filename&quot;, data.filename);
                form.append(&quot;username&quot;, data.username);
                form.append(&quot;password&quot;, data.password);
                form.append(&quot;filebytes&quot;, fdata);
                xmlhttp = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                xmlhttp.open(&quot;POST&quot;, &quot;../AddTo.php&quot;, false);
            }
            xmlhttp.send(form);
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if (++chunk &lt;= chunks)
            {
                loadNext();
            }
            else
            {
                stdlog(&quot;Completed.&quot;);
            }
        };
        fr.readAsText(file.slice(start, end));

    }
    loadNext();
}
```

For some reason, every time I load the XMLHttpRequest, it shows that the file data was never actually sent. Is this because it was too big, or something? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using FileReader?

Comment: @RayNicholus because I am uploading a file too big to send normally, so I am using a FileReader object to read it around 10 megabytes at a time, which should be slow enough.

Comment: This is not what FileReader is used for.  No need to use FileReader to split a file into chunks.  Simply use the slice method on the File object and send the resulting Blob to your server.

Comment: @RayNicholus That would work? Would the blob go to the server as a string or a uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing some basic concepts related to the File API.  My answer here feeds off of the comments from your question.

First off, the proper way to upload a file in chunks is to use [the `slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob) on the `Blob` or `File` object.  The `slice` method will always return another `Blob`.  This `Blob` represents the portion of the `Blob` or `File` you have carved out.  You can then `append` that `Blob` to your `FormData` object.  Your `FormData` object will be sent in a multipart-encoded POST request.  The `Blob` will be represented inside of one of the multipart boundaries in the request as a form field, just like any other parameters you have appended to your `FormData` object.

Server-side, you would read this `Blob` just as you would read any other file when parsing a MPE request.  This `Blob` will need to be temporarily stored server-side, along with any other `Blob`s that make up the complete file.  Once you have received all parts, you will need to assemble them in the correct order server-side.

Your current method involves slicing the file into blobs, reading the entire contents of the blob, and then attaching the contents to your `FormData` object.  This seems redundant and inefficient to me.